# BSOD when connecting to a VPN using Windows 7's built-in service

Tags: windows-7, vpn, bsod

I use two types of VPN services to surf anonymously, the tow types are

1. VPN service that require pre-install software
2. VPN service that uses Windows 7 built in service

When I use the last type, after connecting with vpn server, almost there is a blue screen error happened with code `0x0000007f`.

But when I use the first type there is no such error.

So what is the problem with Windows 7 built in vpn service?

Answer (score 1):

do you see any minidump files created in c:\windows\minidump ? windows typically will create dump files that describe what caused the crash/BSODs. if you have them dump files, you can use [WhoCrashed](http://www.resplendence.com/whocrashed) to analyze the dump. on the first run it will prompt to download MS Debugging tools. screenshots and guide available [here](http://www.raymond.cc/blog/archives/2009/01/17/analyzing-windows-crash-dump-or-minidump-with-whocrashed/).

Answer (score 0):

the problem was in epwf.sys file ,that is eset smart security driver,i uninstall the old AV then i install the new version of the same AV.
Now the problem has gone.